# Why does cmake add_dependencies not work for libraries with CUDA code?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

In cmake you can use `add_dependencies` to make sure that one library is up to date and built before another one. This works perfectly fine for a library with C++ sources (myLib in the example code), however it doesn't work for a library with CUDA sources (myCudaLib in the example code).

First I made sure that all libraries are build. When I now change a file of myLib and build `mainExec`, `myLib` is automatically rebuild before it. If I try the same thing with `myCudaLib` it only tells me that all projects are up to date.

Does anyone know why the changes are not detected and the lib is not rebuild with CUDA files?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(cmakeTest LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

add_executable(mainExec main.cpp)

add_library(myLib foo.h foo.cpp)
add_dependencies(mainExec myLib)
target_link_libraries(mainExec PRIVATE myLib)

add_library(myCudaLib foo.cuh foo.cu)
add_dependencies(mainExec myCudaLib)
target_link_libraries(mainExec PRIVATE myCudaLib)
```

The source files contain nothing significant, only a function void foo() with an empty body (or a single variable when I change them to see if the libs are rebuild).

In case it matters: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017, Cmake 3.13, Cuda 10.0

Comment: Having `target_link_libraries` makes `add_dependencies` redudant. Which exact file of `myCudaLib` you are changing for observe rebuilding? What if you build `myCudaLib` library after such change, will it get rebuilt?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, however the problem remains the same if I omit the add_dependencies (c++ lib gets rebuild if changed, cuda lib not). I have changed both files foo.cuh and foo.cu, neither causes a rebuild. I can manually build all libraries without issues before and after the changes.

Comment: So if you change `foo.cuh` and ask Visual Studio for build `myCudaLib`, then it makes the library rebuilt. But if you change `foo.cuh` and ask Visual Studio for build `mainExec`, then nothing is rebuilt. Am I correctly understand your situation?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what happens.

Comment: Hm, I am not very familiar with CUDA, but from CMake point of view this looks actually strange.

Comment: Actually I have to correct my statement from above: If it rebuilds when I manually click build depends on the location of the project. I found that this is caused by a rather nasty bug in the interaction between Cuda and Visual Studio 2017. I will post more details for people that might have the same problem in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of Visual Studio not detecting changes in CUDA files is caused by a bug in the interaction of CUDA 10.0 (and apparently some of the previous versions) with Visual Studio 2017 (2015 works fine). It doesn't occure if your project is located in certain folders (`C:\ProgramData` and `C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local`). The full discussion on the NVIDIA forum can be found [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1029759/cuda-setup-and-installation/visual-studio-2017-not-detecting-changes-in-cuda-cu-files/).

CUDA 10.1 fixes the bug (not yet confirmed by NVIDIA but seems to work for some people on the forum and it also worked for me).